# AnonymousUser Error when use django-rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I use the [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth)  to generate the token to certificate my APIs, all I have configured fine in my project.

[image]

You see my snapshot top right corner, I have login my `test01` account, using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/`(this is the `django-rest-auth` build-in link)

But when I access the url to `KoleListAPIView`, there comes out issue, says the request is `AnonymousUser`:

```
AttributeError at /api/userproducts/kole/list/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'openstackcloud_id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000//api/userproducts/kole/list/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'kole_id'
```

My views.py is bellow:

```
class KoleListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    """
    list the Kole
    """
    serializer_class = KoleListSerializer
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        kole_id = self.request.user.kole_id  # there comes the issue.
        if kole_id == None:
            return Response(data="please enter the password again", status=HTTP_511_NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED, exception=Exception())
```

---

But I have login the `test01` account.

And my REST_FRAMEWORK in settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[], #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':['rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'],
    'PAGE_SIZE':10
}
```

If I remove the `'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'` in the REST_FRAMEWORK of settings, its also this Error.

Comment: You do not get me, I means I use the django-rest-auth provided the login link, I have login, why I request other API, I still get the `AnonymousUser ` error?

Comment: Could you please update "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES" like this. REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
), in setting.py

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM This works, thank you.

Comment: You can find the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601130/django-rest-framework-using-tokenauthentication-with-browsable-api)